# T-equivariant homology of affine Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, co.combinatorics, schubert-calculus

Let $G=SL_n$, denote the affine Grassmannian $Gr:=Gr_{G}=\mathcal{G}/\mathcal{P}$, where $\mathcal{G}=G(\mathbb{C}((z)))$ and $\mathcal{P}=G(\mathbb{C}[[z]])$. We know that $R:=H_*^T(Gr)\cong H_*^T(\Omega SU(n))$ from Bott and from the multiplication structure of the base loop group, we can make $R$ as a Pontryagin ring so $R$ is indeed a ring over $S:=H^*_T(pt)=Sym(h_{\mathbb{Z}}^*)$ where $h_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the coweight lattice. 
Let $W^0=W_{aff}/W$ where $W_{aff},W=S_n$ are the affine Weyl group and Weyl group of $G$. We know that there is a natural bijection between $W^0$ and the co-root lattice $\check{Q}$. Define the affine Schubert variety as $X_\lambda=\overline{\mathcal{B}\cdot z^{\lambda}}\subset Gr$. Here $\mathcal{B}$ is the Iwahori subgroup.
The homology classes $[X_\lambda]$ form a basis in $R$ over $S$.

From Peterson, we also know that $R\cong Z_{\mathbb{A}_{aff}}(S)$, where $\mathbb{A}_{aff}$ is the affine nilHecke algebra.
Since the $[X_\lambda]$ form a basis, we have the following:
$[X_\lambda][X_\mu]=\sum_{\delta\in \check{Q}} d_{\lambda,\mu}^{\delta}X_\delta$ where $d_{\lambda,\mu}^{\delta}\in S$. 
I think in the ordinary homology case, it has been done by Thomas Lam
,Luc Lapointe ,Jennifer Morse ,Mark Shimozono etc..

**How much do we know in computing these $d_{\lambda,\mu}^{\delta}$?
What about the most basic case when $G$ is just $SL_2$?**